# Min and Steps quantity in Woocommerce cart and single product page for wholesale role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I have this working except for non-wholesale users on the cart page.

Requirements:

- Min quantity of 36
- intervals of 36
- Apply to single-product-page & cart
- `current_user_can('wholesale')`
- `has_term( 'mug', 'product_tag')`

This should work but, it applies the rules in the cart to all users when I need it to effect only wholesale users.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout()  && has_term( 'mug', 'product_tag') && 
    current_user_can('wholesale') ) {
        $args['input_value'] = 36; // Start from this value (default = 1) 
        $args['min_value']   = 36; // Minimum value
        $args['step']        = 36; // Quantity steps
        return $args;
    } else {
        $args['input_value'] = 1; // Start from this value (default = 1) 
        $args['min_value']   = 1; // Minimum value
        $args['step']        = 1; // Quantity steps
        return $args;
    }
}

// Variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' );
function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    if (  has_term( 'mug', 'product_tag') && 
    current_user_can('wholesale') ) {
        $args['input_value'] = 36; // Start from this value (default = 1) 
        $args['min_value']   = 36; // Min quantity (default = 1)
        $args['step']        = 36; // Increment/decrement by this value (default = 1)
        return $args;
    } else {
        $args['min_value']   = 1; // Minimum value
        $args['step']        = 1; // Quantity steps
        $args['input_value'] = 1; // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
        return $args;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** I have tested your code and there is some gliches and mistakes.

**The first function** seems to work but there is some errors and is not recommended to use [`current_user_can()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) conditional function for user roles. You don't need all attributes keys in the else, as most of defaults values are already **`1`**…

**The second function** keys `'input_value'` and 'step' doesn't have any effect as they doesn't exist in the **`$args`** array *(see the official snippet code below or the source code for this hook)*. There is some missing arguments like the `$product`.

**In both functions** there is some mistakes in the condition. I have replaced in your condition `is_checkout()` by `is_product()` as you are targeting single product pages and cart page as you mention in your question.

> You should check and be sure that the correct Wholesale user role slug is `'wholesale'` *(as it could be for example `'wholesale_customer'` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48228552/3730754))*.

You can check code on this official WooCommerce snippet: [Adjust the quantity input values](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adjust-the-quantity-input-values/)…

This revisted code should work on cart page too now:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user(); // Get current WP_User
    if ( ! ( is_cart() || is_product() ) ) return $args;
    if ( ! in_array( 'wholesale', $user->roles ) ) return $args;
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();
    if ( ! has_term( 'mug', 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) return $args;

    // $args['input_value'] = 36; // Start from this value (default = 1)
    $args['min_value']   = 36; // Min value (default = 0)
    $args['step']        = 36; // Quantity steps (default = 1)

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_qty_available_variation_args', 10, 3 );
function custom_qty_available_variation_args( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user(); // Get current WP_User
    if ( ! ( is_cart() || is_product() ) ) return $data;
    if ( ! in_array( 'wholesale', $user->roles ) ) return $data;
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    if ( ! has_term( 'mug', 'product_tag', $product_id ) ) return $data;

    $data['min_qty'] = 36; // Minimum value (default = 1)
    $args['input_value'] = 36; // Start from this value (default = 1)
    $args['min_value']   = 36; // Min value (default = 0)
    $args['step']        = 36; // Quantity steps (default = 1)

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and and almost working.

> It seems that there is a bug in cart page. The products get stucked on 36, even if you increase and update quantities for both simple and variations products…

Comment: Thank you. It's working on the single product page for the main product and each variation, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the cart. Now in cart the quantity rules don't work for any user role.

Comment: The second function is for the variations on the single product page, it does work. I've modified it slightly but to suite my needs but still no joy in the cart.

Comment: The second function I just added
 ` $variation_data['min_qty'] = 36; 
  $variation_data['input_value'] = 36;
        $variation_data['min_value']   = 36; 
        $variation_data['step']        = 36;`

One thing that might be effecting the cart, all the products are variations.

Comment: I tracked it down to the tag. Also sometimes sessions get stored while testing and randomly the cache/cookies needs to needs to be cleared.

Interesting since are not associated with product variations but they are associated with the main product. This doesn't matter on the single product page since the main product and variations are present but in the cart its only the variation and variations don't have tags attached.

Comment: @user2059376 Ok I have updated my code it almost works… But I can't update increased values in cart for both simple or variable products. It stays stucked on 36. For variation tags I have solved the problem calling the parent variable product…

Comment: Yours works for the first function just use `$args['min_value']   = 36; $args['step']        = 36; `
For the second function use `$data['min_qty'] = 36; $data['input_value'] = 36; $data['min_value']   = 36; $data['step']        = 36; `
**Then it doesn't get stuck at 36 in the cart.**